# How do I publish a CustomAction when Dialog is showing

Tags: wix

I have following `Fragment` to define my `CustomAction`s (actually 2 methods in my CA-project)

```
<Fragment>
    <Binary Id="FooAssembly"
            SourceFile="Foo.CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="Action1"
                  BinaryKey="FooAssembly"
                  DllEntry="Action1" />
    <CustomAction Id="Action2"
                  BinaryKey="FooAssembly"
                  DllEntry="Action2" />
</Fragment>
```

My `Action1` looks like this:

```
[Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomAction]
public static ActionResult Action1(Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Session session)
{
    session["value1"] = "some value";
    session["value2"] = "some value";

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Now I need to run this `CustomAction` when my dialog is showing and bind the value `value1` to a `Edit`-control like so:

```
<Dialog Id="FooDlg">
    <Control Id="FooEdit"
             Type="Edit"
             Text="[value1]"
             Property="value1"
             Disabled="yes" />
</Dialog>
```

My `InstallUISequence` looks like this

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="FooDlg"
          After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>
```

I am using an `Edit`-control here, because I need some border - which `Text` is missing - and therefore I need to have the attribute `Property` filled.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by adapting my `InstallUISequence` like

```
  <InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="Action1"
            After="CostFinalize" />
    <Show Dialog="FooDlg"
          After="Action1" />
  </InstallUISequence>
```